# Сравнение экземпляров классов в Python

Tags: python, классы

Всем привет.

Помогите разобраться с магическими методами сравнения.

```
class Trailer_load_capacity:
         
    """ Trailer type class """

    def __init__(self, trailer_length=13.6, trailer_width=2.5, trailer_height=2.6):
        self.trailer_length = trailer_length
        self.trailer_width = trailer_width
        self.trailer_height = trailer_height


class Cargo:

     def __init__(self, cargo_length, cargo_width, cargo_height):
         self.cargo_length = cargo_length
         self.cargo_width = cargo_width
         self.cargo_height = cargo_height
         super().__init__(trailer_length=13.6, trailer_width=2.5, trailer_height=2.6)

     def __lt__(self, trailer_length=13.6):
         if self.cargo_length < trailer_length:
             return 'Your cargo is placed on a trailer'

     def __gt__(self, trailer_length=13.6):
         if self.cargo_length > trailer_length:
             return 'Your cargo is NOT placed on a trailer'

     def __le__(self, trailer_width=2.5):
         if self.cargo_width <= trailer_width:
             return 'The load is placed on a trailer'

     def __ge__(self, trailer_width=2.5):
         if self.cargo_width >= trailer_width:
             return 'Your cargo is NOT placed on a trailer'

     def __eq__(self, trailer_height=2.6):
         if self.cargo_height == trailer_height:
             return 'Load of suitable height'
```

И в примере моего кода, уместно ли наследования в классе Cargo, класса Trailer_load_capacity ? Как в таком случае сделать сравнение между экземпляров двух этих классов?

Comment: Начнем с того, что эти методы должны возвращать True или False, а не строки. Наследоваться уместно, если объект B является объектом A (B - более узкий класс объектов A, например, легковая машина - подкласс автомобилей вообще). Ну и почитайте про принцип подстановки Барбары Лисков. В плане сравнения - чтобы сравнение в принципе было возможно, у объектов должны быть какие-то схожие свойства, по которым их можно сравнивать.

Comment: Программист и Python будут подразумевать что все пять волшебных методов сравнивают объекты одного типа. У вас не так. Это не является ошибкой в строгом смысле, но такие объекты нельзя сортировать, нельзя искать максимум и минимум.